# Eclipse ui not working properly?

Tags: linux, eclipse, user-interface

I just installed Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler) on Linux Mint 16 "Petra", XFCE edition. The fact is, the user interface doesn't seem to be working properly: http://oi59.tinypic.com/2r1zcz4.jpg. Even though it's not affecting anything but appearence it's still quite annoying. What can i do to solve this?

P.s. I also tried a less recent version of Eclipse (3.8, from the ufficial repository) and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse 4.x (Juno and later) has a very varying visual experience on Linux (to be euphemistic), depending on your local theme settings. One difference is that 4.x uses a completely new styling engine, but apparently nobody has taken the time to refine the visual styles on Linux to any noticable degree. I'd recommend starting by installing [Jeeeyul's Eclipse Themes](https://github.com/jeeeyul/eclipse-themes), and see how far that gets you.

Comment: thank you. Actually, i just did that (installed through Eclipse Marketplace). It got a little better.